# Google Maps Api Error: InvalidKeyMapError

Tags: asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I developed an application in Asp.net where I used bees google map for libraries places.
I plugged in the "Maps API bootstrap URL" address for debugging the application, but unfortunately I get the error "Google Maps Api Error: InvalidKeyMapError"; the address is inserted:
`*http://localhost /*`
and I've also included:
`*http://localhost:1055/*` changing the application, but unfortunately I always get the error; I added the pages where name is the url of google, but unfortunately I always get the error ...

How do I call up localhost bees google?

Many thanks to those who respond

dave

Comment: [That error](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key-map-error) is defined as "The API key included in the script element that loads the API is not found. Please make sure you are using a correct API key." - you have to [use a valid API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).

Comment: ok, I have already defined a valid key and added the url to which they refer; outside work but with localhost I get this error ... help!